# Symfony5 / KnpLabs / DoctrineBehaviors / don't record the translation

Tags: symfony5

I am trying to implement KnpLabs / DoctrineBehaviors / Translatable in Symfony 5.2.

I follow the example:
https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/master/docs/translatable.md

I create `Category` and `CategoryTranslation`entities like as the example. And execute `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` correctly.

When I implement into Controller, everything seems to work, but the table `CategoryTranslation` (on mysql) is empty.

```php
// DefaultController.php

use App\Entity\Category; 
use App\Entity\CategoryTranslation; 

public function default()
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 
        $category = new Category();
        $category->translate('fr')->setName('Chaussures');
        $category->translate('en')->setName('Shoes');

        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();

    }
```

Result: table `Category` has a 1 record `id:1` but CategoryTranslation table is empty.

It does not work.

I paste the two entities, but they are the same as the example:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);    

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TranslatableInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\TranslatableTrait;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category implements TranslatableInterface
{
    use TranslatableTrait;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $someFieldYouDoNotNeedToTranslate;
    
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);    

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TranslationInterface;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model\Translatable\TranslationTrait;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CategoryTranslation implements TranslationInterface
{
    use TranslationTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $description;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): void
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the mergeNewTranslations()

As explained in the code from the link you provided.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/** @var \Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Contract\Entity\TranslatableInterface $category */
$category = new Category();
$category->translate('fr')->setName('Chaussures');
$category->translate('en')->setName('Shoes');

$entityManager->persist($category);

// In order to persist new translations, call mergeNewTranslations method, before flush
$category->mergeNewTranslations();

$category->translate('en')->getName();
```

You do ***need*** to call

```
$category->mergeNewTranslations();
```

before you flush to the database or the translations will not be persisted.